# python re matching the "space at the end of string"

Tags: python, regex

original re expression given by MOOC instructor is

```
^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([\w:/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})\] "(\S+) (\S+)\s*(\S*)" (\d{3}) (\S+)
```

I think the catch here is there is an extra space at the end of HTTP/1.0 for bad ones, anyone can hint to make a minor change to make it parse **BOTH** successfully?
I tried to change (\S*) to (?:\s+|$) or (\S.*) and it did not work either way.

## good one below

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Aug/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /images/launch-logo.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 1839
```

## bad one below

```
Invalid logline: ix-li1-14.ix.netcom.com - - [08/Aug/1995:14:47:41 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-70/mission-sts-70.html HTTP/1.0 " 200 20304
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct approach

```
^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([\w:/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})\] "(\S+) (\S+)\s*(\S*)\s?" (\d{3}) (\S+)
```

Notice `\s?` before second `"`.

This matches both

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Aug/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /images/launch-logo.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 1839
```

and

```
ix-li1-14.ix.netcom.com - - [08/Aug/1995:14:47:41 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-70/mission-sts-70.html HTTP/1.0 " 200 20304
```

Comment: Thanks, could you comment why  (?:\s+|$) did not work?

Comment: First of all `$` will match the end of the whole string you pass not the text inside `"`. Thus it does not make sense here. Now we have `(?:\s+)` that is equal to non-capturing `\s+` and it will work only if there is at least one space and should match invalid case only.

Comment: It looks like `\s*` will be less error-prone than `\s?` honestly.